# ¿Se pueden crear llaves foráneas desde phpmyadmin MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo unas tablas desde `MySQL` y me preguntaba si había alguna manera de enlazar las tablas con llaves foráneas como en `acces`.

De ser así, ¿cuál es la forma de implementarlas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Claro que sí, puedes hacerlo de dos  formas:

- De forma gráfica o
- Por sentencia `SQL`

[image: Imagen ejemplo]

Solo debes buscar la opción de diseñador y te mostrará las tablas donde arrastras desde la llave primaria  a la que deseas que sea tu llave foránea.
En sentencia `SQL`:

```
 ALTER TABLE nombreTabla ADD FOREIGN KEY (campodemiTabla) REFERENCES otraTabla (Id);
```

Comment: Jajaja y pensar que era tan simple, gracias por tu ayuda, la imagen ayudó bastante ♥

Comment: @Gabriel recuerda marcar la respuesta si te fue útil

Comment: espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 3):

Por código

```
   ALTER TABLE nombreTabla ADD FOREIGN KEY (campodemiTabla) REFERENCES otraTabla (Id) ;
```