# Como relacionar tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero relacionar multiples tablas

Estoy haciendo un sistema de gestion de inventario en PhP y mis tablas son (proveedores,usuarios,compra,venta,detalles_compra,detalles_venta y producto) y no se como relacionarlas[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes cambiar tu etiqueta ya que la consulta no es de **PHP**. Supongo que es `phpMyadmin` con `MySQL`. Creo que esta pregunta podría ayudarte: [Tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/201982/se-pueden-crear-llaves-for%C3%A1neas-desde-phpmyadmin-mysql)

Comment: Tus tablas ya están relacionado. Por ejemplo la table `detalle_venta` tiene `factura_venta_id` y así el detalle está relacionado a su venta. Solamente te faltan las lineas para hacer estas relaciones visible en tu diagrama. Si este diagrama resulta de una aplicación para modelar tu base de data, es que todavía no has creado los foreign keys, y así tu programa no sabe de la relación, porque no se fía a nombres.

Answer (score 3):

Tengo una buena noticia para ti: tus tablas ya están relacionadas, pero aún no lo sabes. Me explico: cada tabla que creas modela una **entidad**, un concepto del mundo real con una serie de atributos en común (facturas, proveedores, productos, ...) éstas entidades se relacionan con otras a través de lo que el **modelo ER** *(Peter Chen, 1976)* llamó precisamente **relaciones**, que finalmente se materializarán en otras tablas (las cuales eventualmente podremos eliminar cuando las cardinalidades nos lo permitan) que vincularán las entidades entre sí.

Estas *relaciones* ya existen en la realidad que estás modelando, las *entidades* son los *nombres* y las *relaciones* los *verbos*:

- Los `usuarios` `reciben` `facturas_venta`
- Los `proveedores` `emiten` `facturas_compra`
- Las `facturas` `detallan` `productos`

Únicamente te queda convertirlas en tablas para que las puedas tener en cuenta en tu modelo. Esto sería pasar del modelo *conceptual ER* al *relacional*. En tu caso concreto, como una factura sólo puede ser emitida por un único usuario o proveedor *(cardinalidad 1:N)*, no te hace falta implementar esas tablas `reciben` o `emiten`, propagas el `id` del usuario y del proveedor a la `factura` y te ahorras esa tabla intermedia que hay quien llama *pivote o join table*. Con `detallan` no es posible realizar esta simplificación, pues una `factura` sí que puede contener varios `productos`, *(cardinalidad N:M)*.

En definitiva, que tu modelo ya cuenta con todas las relaciones que necesita, no tienes por qué verlas para que existan.

Otra cuestión diferente, y probablemente sea a lo que te refieras en tu pregunta, es la definición de restricciones para impedir que, por ejemplo, emitamos facturas a clientes inexistentes. *Microsoft* llamó a eso relaciones, cuando en realidad son claves ajenas o FK  *(foreign keys)*. Para la FK entre `factura_compra` y `proveedores`, lo puedes hacer en MySQL con un simple:

```
ALTER TABLE factura_compra
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(fk_id_proveedores)
  REFERENCES proveedores(proveedores_id);
```

Tras definir las FK quedan unos diagramas muy visuales y fáciles de seguir, pero no garantizan que tu base de datos esté correctamente *"relacionada"*. Las relaciones las establece la semántica (el significado de lo que quieres modelar), no las restricciones, y siempre las podrás ver en el modelo ER, no necesariamente en la implementación física de la base de datos en un sistema gestor.

Y otra cuestión, hay sistemas en los que, por cuestiones de rendimiento para ahorrarse tiempo de computación comprobando restricciones, las FK no llegan a implementarse. Funcionan perfectamente, cuando hay millones de registros son más rápidas, es un infierno entenderlas, pero la relación conceptual sigue existiendo aunque no uses las FK.

Cuando realices consultas para obtener, por ejemplo, la facturación de cada cliente. Tendrás que conectar la información que te interese de varias tablas entre sí para poder hacer los cálculos necesarios. Hay quien al *JOIN* o *conexión*, lo llama relacionar tablas. De hecho, en el GQBE de Access, utilizan las **FK** para proponerte los **JOIN**, que resulta muy cómodo en la mayoría de los casos, pero no es necesariamente lo debes hacer para resolver determinadas consultas en las que haya que conectar una tabla consigo misma o a través de un campo calculado.

Y ya, para rematar la confusión, tenemos una cuarta acepción de la palabra **relación** para referirnos a las tablas, pues no dejan de ser una *relación* de datos en el sentido de conjunto de datos almacenados con un cierto orden. De ahí lo de *bases de datos relacionales*, no porque vinculemos tablas, sino porque toda la información se guarda en tablas.

Me consta que esto te resultará un poco confuso, pero es la consecuencia de llamar a cuatro cosas distintas por el mismo nombre. Espero habértelo aclarado.

La **normalización** es ir un paso más allá, siempre con el objetivo de evitar **redundancias** que lleven a **inconsistencias** en los datos. El ejemplo más típico es el de mantener dos agendas con números de teléfonos de tus contactos. Ahí tendrías la *redundancia*, la *inconsistencia* llegaría en cuanto un contacto cambia su número de teléfono y sólo actualizas el dato en una de tus agendas. La [teoría matemática](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos) que la respalda es muy amplia, *(formas normales, Reglas de Codd)*, y, para que te quedes con una idea simple y funcional, *mete cada dato que se repita en una tabla distinta*. Esto sería, si varios *detalles* de tu *factura* comparten datos comunes, como el número de factura o la fecha de emisión, eso te estará indicando que debes tener una tabla para las `facturas` y otra diferente para el `detalle` de cada producto con aquellos datos que NO se repiten: cantidad, descuentos, precio de venta... Lo habitual es que, a partir del modelo ER, obtengas una tercera forma normal *3FN*, pero puedes normalizar aún más, extrayendo las `provincias` de la tabla `proveedores` conectándolas a través de un `id_provincia` que te evite tener que escribir en cada cliente el nombre de cada provincia. Espero haber podido darte una visión general sobre la teoría y te resulte más sencillo entenderla.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Disculpa, que no me he leido toda la respuesta pero de casualidad agregaste en ella los tipos de relaciones 121, 12M y M21 y la teoria de 2FN y 3FN, y un poquito sobre tablas intermedia de relacion... la verdad me interesa esa parte pero no me veo colocando una pregunta ... y que al final la cataloguen como basada en opiniones...

Comment: La he respondido basándome en una teoría ampliamente aceptada y con más de cuarenta años de recorrido... Puedo estar interpretándola mal, pero poco veo opinable aquí... :)

Comment: Normalmente, cuando argumentas por qué no está basada en opiniones, no llegan a cerrarla

Comment: Espera, no estoy diciendo que esta pregunta este basada en opiniones... solo queria saber si podes profundisar un poco mas en los puntos que he comentado.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 He ampliado la respuesta comentando la normalización sobre la que preguntabas. Sobre las cardinalidades ya hablaba en el tercer párrafo. La teoría de bases de datos es muy extensa y existen muchas formas de explicarla. No temas preguntar, a veces una respuesta informal te puede dar más claridad que profundizar en exceso en la teoría.

Comment: Tengo una duda, cuando algo el modelo en phpMyAdmin me salen todos los campos con un simbolo (#) , este simbolo es el de la clave foranea entonces porque le sale a todas?

Comment: No uso mucho el phpMyAdmin, pero crea una nueva pregunta añadiendo tu dataset en SQL, con phpmyadmin, exportar, y lo reproducimos a ver qué puede ser...